# Footer contains "Legal" and "Terms of Service", but they are pointing to the same page

Tags: discussion, footer, terms-of-service

Site footer has a link for "Legal" (https://stackoverflow.com/legal) and a link for "Terms of Service" (https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service). I noticed the former page is redirected to the latter page. So these two links are the same.

How about merging these two links in footer?

[image]

Comment: Is it normal for a site's "legal" footer link (which is relatively common I think) to link to their terms of service? I really didn't expect that redirect, though I'm not familiar with what else would be there instead.